# Reshape multivariate Time series using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following time series Dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(120, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['date']=pd.date_range(start="2012-01-01",
                      #end='2022-12-01',
                      periods=1 * 120,
                      freq='MS')
df.set_index('date',inplace=True,drop=True)
df['month']=df.index.month
df['year']=df.index.year
```

I need to reshape that dataframe in python pandas as below:

```
Year    City      Jan   Feb  ...  Dec
 2012    A         10     15       12
 2013    A         13     17       10
 2014    A         12     10       15
 ...    ...       ...   ...       ...
 2012    B         30     40       33
 2013    B         16     22       16
 2014    B         7      24       44 
 ...    ...       ...   ...       ... 
 ...    ...       ...   ...       ... 
 2021    D         19     17       45
```

My code is

```
df_table= pd.pivot_table(df, values=df.columns, index="year", 
columns='month',sort=False)
```

my result is:

```
       A                  ...   D                
month  1   2   3   4   5   ...  8   9   10  11  12
year                       ...                    
2012   54  21  53  95  39  ...  47  41  40  91   9
2013   91  36  51  32  17  ...  68   8  36  89  48
2014   44   9  26  28  47  ...   1   9  23  55  21
2015   35  36  68  71  67  ...   5  88  34  56  80
2016   70  14  48  45  20  ...  81  47  33  17  22
2017   68  43  25  69  13  ...  76  17  79  10  79
2018   94   9   9  40  19  ...  76   5  54  27  41
2019   82  84  93  65  20  ...  54  92  49  24  91
2020   95  66  12  60  45  ...  66  47  19  35  42
2021   95  78  37  31  23  ...  78  12  78  70  43

[10 rows x 48 columns]
```

So I need to know what is the problem in my code or any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt):

```
out = (df.melt(['month', 'year'], var_name='City', ignore_index=False)
         .pivot_table(index=['year', 'City'], columns='month', values='value', fill_value=0)
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

*NB. if you want, `df['month'] = df.index.month_name()` will give your the month name.*

Output:

```
    year City   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
0   2012    A  17  58  41  46  14  42   6  76  20  79  49  64
1   2012    B  79  31  57  82  99  84  68  52  99  13  69  95
2   2012    C   4   1  35  91  53  75  47  78  58  85  41  69
3   2012    D  42  65  11   0  12  68   3  15  23  48  35  94
4   2013    A   0  48  42   0  23  62  82  81  41  10   2  54
5   2013    B  50  93  77  10  59  35  46  50  58  86  51   0
6   2013    C  36   3  21  43   2  94  99  27  65  43  80  38
7   2013    D  34  98  73  58  98  67  20  14  36  11  32  19
8   2014    A  46  77   3  40  72  67   4  77  24  80  33  31
9   2014    B  42  30  94  72  26  61  67  75  29  60  32  13
10  2014    C  56  24  98  19  66  14  11  56  21  61  70  71
11  2014    D  60   2  13  95  52  96  86  16  25  83  85  56
12  2015    A  24  40  38  44  82  86  43  10   2  23  20  35
13  2015    B  79  54  93  88   3  61  32  54  27  53  53  39
14  2015    C  41  79   1  24  76  69  11  37  83  51  29   9
15  2015    D  18  11  95  67  35  87  84  28  89  46  67  73
16  2016    A  41  90   9  71  97  88   0  53  61  91  25  29
17  2016    B  23  50  10  39  44  33  75  80   1  40  67  33
18  2016    C   3   3  27  61  34   5  34  62  81  36  35  18
19  2016    D  46  31  45  85  34  36  69   8  35  48  30  17
20  2017    A  93  12  85  22  71  83  46  96  81  63  24   8
21  2017    B  84  44  39  30  18  49  21  91  58  16  63  56
22  2017    C   2  66  39  17  92  41  73  73   0  36  67  91
23  2017    D  69  91  75  70  43  93  89  28  86  94  51  93
24  2018    A  87  71  81  92  42  20  99  61   8  11  45  49
25  2018    B  32  87  55  36  14  82  83  13  79   4  26  91
26  2018    C  19  13  64  25  86  68   7   5  79  39  74  51
27  2018    D  72  58  75  32  28  22  72   0  53  92  52  99
28  2019    A  18  53  18  70  59  58  13   8  22  99  84  16
29  2019    B  34  58  45  53  80  49  70  13  79   6  89  56
30  2019    C  51  43  87  48  26  73  38   7  89  81  66  23
31  2019    D  30  55  65  94  35  44  39  80   8  71  60  24
32  2020    A   4  54  57  33   7  83   3  36  10  63   9  83
33  2020    B  49  25  23  53   9  36  42  68  94  31  60  76
34  2020    C  87  20  27  51  54  81  65  80  91  20  91  18
35  2020    D  30  97  29  86   0  20  20  47  43  70  35  74
36  2021    A  98  12  39  99  98  28  51  33  84  91  83  91
37  2021    B  97  58  24  69  40  68  73   7   7  67  95  30
38  2021    C  43   1  58   6  60  26  53  94  67  84   0  73
39  2021    D   3   0  36   3  33  96  69  72  85  71   5  83
```

Comment: Thanks, mozway, I got what I need using your code